# Error: Reverse for 'detail_page' not found. 'detail_page' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django

I trying to create own page for each post(detail), but when I am launching page with all post, I have this error: **Reverse for 'detail_page' not found. 'detail_page' is not a valid view function or pattern name.** When I delete

```
<a...>
```

in

```
<h3 class="name-detail"><a href="{% url 'detail_page' pk=detail.pk %}">{{ detail.detail }} для {{ detail.car }}</a></h3>
```

all is working

views.py:

```
...
def porshe_cayenne(request):
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(Detail.objects.filter(car="Porsche Cayenne")[::-1], 20)
    images = DetailImage.objects.all()
    try:
        details = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        details = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        details = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request, 'shop/list.html', {'details': details, 'images':images})

def detail_page(request, pk):
    detail = get_object_or_404(Detail, pk=pk)
    images = DetailImage.objects.filter(detail=detail)
    return render(request, 'shop/detail.html', {'detail': detail, 'images':images})
```

list.html:

```
...
<div class="infinite-container">
        {% for detail in details %}
            <div class="background_detail">
                <div class="detail">
                    <h3 class="name-detail"><a href="{% url 'detail_page' pk=detail.pk %}">{{ detail.detail }} для {{ detail.car }}</a></h3> #HERE IS PROBLEM
                    <br>
                    <h6>{{ detail.description }} <em class="fa fa-arrow-down"></em> Всі контакти внизу <em class="fa fa-arrow-down"></em></h6>
                    <br>
                    {% for img in images %}
                        {% if img.detail == detail %}
                            <img class="detail-foto" src="{{ img.image.url }}" />
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                    <br>
                    <div class="price">
                        Ціна: {{ detail.price }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
...
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^porshe_cayenne/$', views.porshe_cayenne, name='porshe_cayenne'),
url(r'^detail/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.detail_page, name='detail_page'),
```

models.py:

```
class Detail(models.Model):
    car = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    detail = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=30)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.detail

def __str__(self):
    return self.detail

class DetailImage(models.Model):
    detail = models.ForeignKey(Detail, related_name='images',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='details', null = True, blank = True)
```

Comment: is that your main urls.py which you posted?

Comment: No, it is shop.urls.py, main-mysite.urls.py

Answer (score 0):

You've given that URL a name of "detail_page_plz", for some reason.